# MySQL: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I know this has been asked plenty times before, but I cant find an answer that is close to mine.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.cases_ID, c.cases_status, c.cases_title, ci.custinfo_FName, ci.custinfo_LName, c.cases_timestamp, o.organisation_name 
FROM db_cases c, db_custinfo ci, db_organisation o 
WHERE c.userInfo_ID = ci.userinfo_ID AND c.cases_status = '2' 
AND organisation_name = (
    SELECT organisation_name 
    FROM db_sites s, db_cases c 
    WHERE organisation_ID = '111'
)
AND s.sites_site_ID = c.sites_site_ID)
```

What I am trying to do is is get the cases, where the sites_site_ID which is defined in the cases, also appears in the db_sites sites table alongside its organisation_ID which I want to filter by as defined by "organisation_ID = '111'" but I am getting the response from MySQL as stated in the question.

I hope this makes sense, and I would appreciate any help on this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states your subquery returns more then one row which it cannot do in this situation. If this is not expect results you really should investigate why this occurs. But if you know this will happen and want only the first result use `LIMIT 1` to limit the results to one row.

```
SELECT organisation_name 
FROM db_sites s, db_cases c 
WHERE organisation_ID = '111'
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is, obviously, that your subquery returns more than one row which is invalid when using it as a scalar subquery such as with the = operator in the WHERE clause.

Instead you could do an inner join on the subquery which would filter your results to only rows that matched the ON clause. This will get you all rows that match, even if there is more than one returned in the subquery.

UPDATE:
You're likely getting more than one row from your subquery because you're doing a cross join on the db_sites and db_cases table. You're using the old-style join syntax and then not qualifying any predicate to join the tables on in the WHERE clause. Using this old style of joining tables is not recommended for this very reason. It would be better if you explicitly stated what kind of join it was and how the tables should be joined.

Good pages on joins:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html (for the right syntax)
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html (for the differences between the types of joins)

Answer (score 0):

I was battling this for an hour, and overcomplicated it completely. Sometimes a quick break and writing it out on an online forum can solve it for you ;)

Here is the query as it should be.

```
SELECT c.cases_ID, c.cases_status, c.cases_title, ci.custinfo_FName, ci.custinfo_LName, c.cases_timestamp, c.sites_site_ID 
FROM db_cases c, db_custinfo ci, db_sites s 
WHERE c.userInfo_ID = ci.userinfo_ID AND c.cases_status = '2' AND (s.organisation_ID = '111' AND s.sites_site_ID = c.sites_site_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Let me re-write what you have post:

SELECT 
    c.cases_ID, c.cases_status, c.cases_title, ci.custinfo_FName, ci.custinfo_LName, 
    c.cases_timestamp, c.sites_site_ID 
FROM
    db_cases c
JOIN   
    db_custinfo ci ON c.userInfo_ID = ci.userinfo_ID and c.cases_status = '2'
JOIN   
    db_sites s ON s.sites_site_ID = c.sites_site_ID and s.organization_ID = 111
```